# ReferenceError and Confused response on the batch of JSONP requests in jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsonp

I try to request a series of jsonp data by jQuery .Ajax(). For some reason, I have to make the option jsonpCallback  as 'parseResponse'.and I have founded some  strange problem.

When I deal with one jsonp request ,everything is ok. But  when I try to deal with a series of  jsonp requests sent by a loop, I found tow problems:

1. Some request can get correct response and some others can not. Which request can be successful seemed is random. (The result of each run of the script is different)
2. One and only one console error(Uncaught ReferenceError: parseResponse is not defined) is triggered every time the script is run. Even if multiple JSONP requests have been issued by loop.

I'm sure the response of the URLs for jsonp is correct. My code is here, you can run it and see result.

```js
var url = "http://jsfiddle.net/echo/jsonp/";

aj('sigle');

for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    aj('loop' + i);
}

function aj(s) {
    $.ajax({
        url : url,
        dataType : 'jsonp',
        jsonpCallback : 'parseResponse',
    }).fail(function(jqXHR) {
        console.log(s + ' - F');
        
    }).done(function(res) {
        console.log(s + ' - S');
        
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Why is it so? Any kind one can help me? Thanks.

Comment: Please specify the language you are using. See also [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Sorry, I have added it. it is jQuery(javascript).